# How to correctly use inline svg's (with use)

Tags: html, svg

I am using several .svg graphics in my html 5 document that need to be recolored via javascript. Also loading times need to be as short as possible.
The best way I found to doing this is using `<use>`. This (should) integrate the svg into the DOM which can then easily be manipulated by javascript code. It doesn't work for me though if i want to load the svg from a seperate file (not anywhere else in the html file).

My code looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<use xlink:href="/resources/svgs/test.svg"/></svg>
```

I noticed that most examples use `...test.svg#someID` but even if I use the id of some symbol from the svg it doesn't work. If I define a inline (copy and paste) svg somewhere else in the page and then href the id of that svg it works though.
Where is my error?
Is there a better method to using svg's?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the other svg file from where I want to import the svg has <defs> around the <symbols>. Is there any idea how to solve this? Any other way to do this perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works exactly like this. Use `<defs>` with `<symbols>` and `xlinks:href`. Only disadvantage I can see is that these svgs are injected as shadow dom, so you can't really change them with jQuery.